# How to POST get response information on alert dialog when clicking submit?

Tags: java, android, post, okhttp

I need help with this, I'm stuck with alert dialog showing POST response.

I'm trying to POST get response from server, I need to get response when clicking submit (with alert dialog). Can anyone help? I'm new to Java too, any advice or suggestion for my coding?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etUsername = findViewById(R.id.et_username);
    etPassword = findViewById(R.id.et_password);
    btSubmit = findViewById(R.id.bt_submit);
    TextView mTextViewResult;
    mTextViewResult = findViewById(R.id.text_view_result);

    btSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



            if (etUsername.getText().toString().equals("admin") &&
            etPassword.getText().toString().equals("admin")) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        MainActivity.this
                );


                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

                RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                        .add("id", "2020136")
                        .add("token", "Yvj7CbE@B7qrv#Ny_MRPg+S_kqjFrNkcXEF=Faf7Q$*#YFrTHkr-Y=hqwNQEbcEfZ_ahB=u8v=9rh=nhVS#UA8ZH2v!kc9e$+My3VcK@7XyQ-pMs5Mr^*Dmj*RuEKux=")
                        .build();

                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("https://pltmuar.eschool.edu.my/app/findByStudentId.php")
                        .post(formBody)
                        .build();

                builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_check);
                builder.setTitle("Login Successful !");
                builder.setMessage("Welcome to Eschool System");



                builder.setNegativeButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                         "Invalid Username & Password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: it's able to get POST response just using textview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to do with [Jsoup](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup):

```
    // CREATE CONNECTION
    Connection conn = Jsoup.connect("URL_GOES_HERE");
    
    // ADD POST/FORM DATA
    conn.data("KEY", "VALUE");
    
    // SET METHOD AS POST 
    conn.method(Connection.Method.POST);
    
    // ACCEPT RESPONDING CONTENT TYPE
    conn.ignoreContentType(true);
    
    try
    {
        // GET RESPONSE
        String response = conn.execute().body();
        
        // USE RESPONSE HERE
        // CREATE JSON OBJECT OR ANYTHING...
    } catch(HttpStatusException e)
    {
        int status = e.getStatusCode();
        // HANDLE HTTP ERROR HERE
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        // HANDLE IO ERRORS HERE
    }
```